# Check whether variable with the name of array value is set or not

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array:

```
$myArray = array('myVar', 'myVar75', 'myVar666');
```

How do I `isset` check whether the variable called `$myVar`,`$myVar75`,`$myVar666` exists or not?

What is the most sensible way of passing the array's value into the `isset()` function as a variable name to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to test each element with a simple foreach loop:

Example:

```
$myVar666 = 1; // for example's sake
$myArray = array('myVar', 'myVar75', 'myVar666');
foreach($myArray as $element) {
    if(isset(${$element})) {
        echo $element, ' is already set';
    } else {
        echo $element, ' is not yet set';
        // if not set, do something here
    }
}
```

Should yield something like this:

```
$myVar is not yet set 
$myVar75 is not yet set 
$myVar666 is already set
```

Comment: i think he want to create variable first with the values of array and then want to use isset on thiose variables

Comment: @Anant `$myVar666` above is just an example, just to demonstrate the output, the OP could just do anything within the if block whatever the OP decides to do

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($myArray as $value){
    if(isset($$value)){
        echo "$value is exist with value : '".$$value."'";
    }
    else{
        "$value is not exist";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do that by putting an extra $, as follows:

```
$myArray = array("myVar", "myVar75", "myVar666");

if (isset($$myArray[0])) {
    //Content
}
```

That would check if $myVar is set. Change the index to myArray accordingly.

The way to think about PHP's implementation of this (called variable variables) is that the content of the string goes after the dollar sign:

$hi = "hello";

But if you put $$hi, then the $hi is replaced with the string's content, so it becomes $hello.

$hi = "hello";

$hello = "greetings";

If you put $$$hi, then the $hi is replaced so that it becomes $$hello, and the $hello is replaced so that it becomes $greetings.